# order by count from another table

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by, left-join

I hope itll be legal to post this as i'm aware of other similar posts on this topic. But im not able to get the other solutions to work, so trying to post my own scenario. Pretty much on the other examples  like this one, im unsure how they use the tablenames and rows. is it through the punctuation?

```
 SELECT bloggers.*, COUNT(post_id) AS post_count
    FROM bloggers LEFT JOIN blogger_posts 
    ON bloggers.blogger_id = blogger_posts.blogger_id
    GROUP BY bloggers.blogger_id
    ORDER BY post_count
```

I have a table with articles, and a statistics table that gets new records every time an article is read. I am trying to make a query that sorts my article table by counting the number of records for that article id in the statistics table. like a "sort by views" functions.

my 2 tables:

**article**

```
id
```

**statistics**

```
pid <- same as article id
```

Looking at other examples im lacking the left join. just cant wrap my head around how to work that. my query at the moment looks like this:
    $query = "SELECT *, COUNT(pid) AS views FROM statistics GROUP BY pid ORDER BY views DESC";

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT article.*, COUNT(statistics.pid) AS views
FROM article LEFT JOIN statistics ON article.id = statistics.pid
GROUP BY article.id
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Ideas:

- Combine both tables using a join
- If an article has no statistics, fill up with `NULL`, i.e. use a left join
- `COUNT` only counts non-`NULL` values, so count by right table to give correct zero results
- `GROUP BY` to obtain exactly one result row for every article, i.e. to count statistics for each article individually

Comment: Thank you so much! Seeing this example with my own structure makes me understand alot more.  big ups! =)

Comment: if i was to add a WHERE clause into this, where would it go?